# jQuery class selector and 'this' reference

Tags: jquery-selectors

Here is a problem: i need to select elements on page by css class, and then set their width = parentElement.width - 1.
So code looks like this: `$j('.innerCellElement').width(this.parentElement.clientWidth - 1);`
When i say `this` i mean current element of selector. However, is not interpreted how i want. I can do loops here but i want to know if there is an elegant way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery ≥1.4.1, [the `.width()` method](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2) can take a function as input:

```
$('.innerCellElement').width(function(){ return this.parentElement.clientWidth - 1; });
```

otherwise, loop over the collection.

```
$('.innerCellElement').each(function(){
  $(this).width(this.parentElement.clientWidth - 1);
});
```